# I am trying to unhide a blank named folder in my usb flash

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace Diamond
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filepath = @"j:";
            getfiles(filepath);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static void getfiles(string filePath)
        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetDirectories(filePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                fileAttributes(file);
            }
        }

        public static void fileAttributes(string path)
        {
            FileAttributes att = File.GetAttributes(path);

                att = RemoveAtt(att, FileAttributes.Hidden | FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
                File.SetAttributes(path, att);
                Console.WriteLine(path);
        }

        private static FileAttributes RemoveAtt(FileAttributes att, FileAttributes attributesToRemove)
        {
            return att & ~attributesToRemove;
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: this is the problem that pops up when I run the program=>` An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Invalid File or Directory attributes value`.

Answer (score 0):

For me your code worked fine, so can you tell in which line the exception shows up. I guess it is `File.SetAttributes(path, att);`. And then check what file/directory you are processing. Again, i guess it is something like a system file where your attributes are not allowed.

The documentation on `File.SetAttributes(path, att);` says:

> ArgumentException: Path is empty, contains only white spaces, contains
>   invalid characters, or the file attribute is invalid.

So it should be the last part.

You could change the code like this to print the error message and continue with the other files:

```
    public static void fileAttributes(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            FileAttributes att = File.GetAttributes(path);

            att = RemoveAtt(att, FileAttributes.Hidden | FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
            File.SetAttributes(path, att);
            Console.WriteLine(path);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this way

```
var file = new FileInfo(filePath);
if (!file.Exists)
{
    file.Create();

    // Necessary line!
    // Create it again to get valid file attributes
    file = new FileInfo(filePath);
}

file.Attributes |= FileAttributes.Hidden;
```